# Store integer values as a string in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

Following code print integer values:

```
for ( i=0 ; i<COL ; i++ )
{           
    fprintf(iOutFile,"%02x ",(int)(iPtr[offset]));      
}
```

I want to store these integer values as a string in a character pointer. To do so, I tried following code but it does not work.

```
    char *hexVal="";
    char *temp;
    int val;

    for ( i=0 ; i<COL ; i++ )
    {           
       fprintf(iOutFile,"%02x ",(int)(iPtr[offset]));
       val = (int)(iPtr[offset]);      
       temp=(char*) val;
       hexVal = strcat(hexVal,temp);      
    }
    printf("%s", hexVal);
```

Thanx.......

Answer (score 1):

You are getting undefined behavior since there is no writable memory at `hexVal`, which just points at a read-only area containing a character with the value 0. It is a valid string, but it's constant and has length 0, you cannot append to it.

Also, of course you can't cast an integer into a "string", that's just not how C works. This:

```
temp=(char*) val;
```

simply re-interprets the value of `val` as a pointer (i.e. as an address), it doesn't magically compute the proper sequence of digit characters used to represent the address, i.e. it doesn't convert `val` to a string.

You can use `snprintf()` to convert an integer to a string.

So, to summarize:

- Change `hexval`'s declaration into e.g. `char hexval[32] = "";`, this declares it as an array of 32 characters, giving you plenty of space into which to build a number as a string. It *also* initializes the array so the first character is 0, thus making it into an empty string (with space to grow).
- Use e.g. `snprintf(tmp, sizeof tmp, "%d", 4711);` to format a number into a string (which should be e.g. `char tmp[16];`) in decimal form.
- Use `strcat(hexval, tmp);` to concatenate the newly built numeric string onto `hexval`.
- *BEWARE* that you can't concatenate forever, you will run out of space if you do it too long. Adjust the sizes, in that case.
- Check return values where possible, read the manual pages (Google `man FUNCTION` where `FUNCTION` is a standard C library function like `strcat`).

Comment: `hexVal` is initialised, but it points to a read-only area of the process containing simply a `\0`.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev D'oh, I can't read any more. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: If two answers combinedly solve my problem, which one should I accept as answer?

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
char* hexVal = "";
```

you are setting hexVal to point to a string literal, later in your code you try to strcat to that address which will cause undefined behavior.

What you need to do is to allocate a large enough area to hold your resulting string and then let hexVal point to that.

E.g.

```
char* hexVal = malloc(100); // or how much bytes you need
```

then just do

```
strcat(hexVal, temp);
```

alt. allocate on stack

```
char hexVal[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this wrong. In general, if you have an `int i` then you can't just typecast a `char *cp` to the address (or the value) of `i` and expect it to magically become a string that you can `printf` or use in `strcat`. For one thing, strings are null-terminated and don't have a fixed length, while `int`s have a fixed size of typically 32 bits long.

You have to create a separate buffer (memory space) where `snprintf` will happily create a string-representation of your `int` value for you.

I think that your question is more about understanding how programming, pointers and C work in general, than about `int`s and strings and their conversion.